# What adjective is being used here before "Abfahrt" in this video?

Tags: meaning, translation

So, as a Belgian and as fan of trains, I like to listen to the announcements in the stations, but I've always wondered what adjective the German voice is using in front of the word "Abfahrt". It seems something like "gleichermessig" (this is probably totally wrong). I assume this means something like "expected departure". In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D45YQqDrrqo&t=180s), that word is said. You should start listening from minute 3:00.

Comment: It is “planmäßige Abfahrt”.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Planmäßig does not mean expected but orinally scheduled. In terms of the notoriously late DB, the expected time is rarely the originally intended one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word was "planmäßig" in "planmäßige" Abfahrt, it means departure according to plan/scheduled departure.

PS: this is not a German train station and the train is not announced to be late, they are only announcing the track number.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. I deleted the nonrelated discussion, if you want to know, try german.meta. You might consider a more complete sentence rather the very short "dictionary entry".

Comment: @ShegitBrahm, thanks for your welcome. You're a nice person. I may be new to the german SE, but I have been on SE long enough, and I am a contrarian, I never get used to SE`s culture of closing down and voting down what enriches our understanding of the world. Nor do I get used to people answering in comments and leaving the question open and the original asker never coming back to accept an answer, that's a bit of a waste of time. But I have no time for meta-discussions outside of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the inclusion. Well, yeah, ... the help encourages to copy comments into a full answer. I find it nice that it is explicitly stated. So, see you next time^^

Comment: Oh I know that this isn't a German station, it's Antwerpen-Centraal in Belgium! :)